How to remove duplicates in kusto query language
Here I have two columns in the table, the same operation_Id column has 2 or more different language. Need to pick only one operation_Id from the table.
operation_Id    languageenter image description here
12d83416-0c94-4c98-9523-603b7e634a14    en-US
642bb5d7-69e5-437a-b086-d89eec93438b    en-GB
642bb5d7-69e5-437a-b086-d89eec93438b    en-US
642bb5d7-69e5-437a-b086-d89eec93438b    ja-JP
|distinct Operation_Id,language
|summarize cnt=count() by Operation_Id,language
| where cnt<=1
|project Operation_Id,language


How to remove duplicates in kusto query language

Use below code to remove duplicates. It uses distinct operator to remove duplicates and below is the output of the code.
datatable(operation_id:string, language:string)
[
    "1", "en-US",
    "2", "en-GB",
    "2", "en-US",
    "2", "ja-JP"
]
| summarize language = arg_min(language, *) by operation_id
| project operation_id, language
| distinct *

Output:

